# Compare dates in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have date in MYSQL table in the following format 
"2014-01-04" & the field name is "date".
I want all the database entries (Table name : wp_seasons) for last 3 days by comparing this "date" field & current date. 
Can anyone suggest what will be the MYSQL query?

Comment: Don't use strings for dates. Doing so for such queries requires stupid extra conversions. Refer to [Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for how to subtract the cutoff date.

Comment: Use a [*DATE*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) column.

Comment: And don't call a column `DATE` as it is a reserved word, while mysql may understand you, it may be confusing for other humans, and lead to unexpected problems. Also, "date" is not descriptive enough. Something like `start_date` would be better.

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/php/phpdate/php-date-compare-dates.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use mysql [DateDiff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function

```
SELECT * FROM Tablename  WHERE DATEDIFF(now(),date) <=3
```

Comment: @Deepak  i have tried this with date field as string.

Comment: From the mysql manual ,DATEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. so string comes under expression i guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $query="SELECT * FROM Tablename Where date < "strtotime(date('d_m_y'));
  mysql_query($query);
?>
```

Comment: I want to compare date, not to search by a specific date

Answer (score 0):

If date in your table is string then either u have to convert this string into DateTime of MySql

or

you have to create the three Php Date time object and compare as the @Maulik suggested..

```
<?php
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$p1_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today .' -1 day'));
$p2_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today .' -2 day'));

 $query="SELECT * FROM Tablename Where date=".$today." or date=".$p1_date." or date=".$p2_date ;
  mysql_query($query);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `wp_seasons` WHERE DATE(date) = DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL 3 DAY)